# Comparing RMSE/MSE of original data and log10-values of the same data

Tags: regression, model, logarithm, mse, rms

I want to see if my models work better on the original data or on log10 transformed data. But how can I do this? Normally I train the model, calculate the RMSE/MSE on the test data and compare these values. But how can I compare this to log10 transformed data? Is it enough to backtransform the RMSE/MSE values by calculating 10^RMSE of the log10 transformed data model? Or do I have to backtransform the observed and predicted y values first and claculate the RMSE/MSE afterwards? Or is there another way for comparing models with original data to models with log10 transformed data?

Comment: What, in your mind, would it mean to work better?

Comment: Do you want to log transform the reponse (y), the features (x), a subset of the features? What evaluation metric have you been using so far?

Comment: typically you would have one scale you care about- I am assuming the original. So then you would reverse the transformation and then calculate rmse. to reverse the transformation you need to take into account the variability. https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2013/08/forecasting-from-log-linear-regressions.html